# Alexnet tensorflow implementation very low accuracy

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning

I try to implement [Alexnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AlexNet) using basic tensorflow python api by myself, but during training, I get some unexpected output and the test accuracy is quiet low.

Dataset for training: [oxford17](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/data/flowers/17/)

Here is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tflearn.datasets.oxflower17 as oxflower17
from IPython import embed

# network trainning metavariables
learning_rate = 0.001
batch_size = 64
log_dir = './tflog/alexnet/'

# define input size
image_width = 224
image_height = 224
image_depth = 3
num_labels = 17

# initialize datasets
print('-----Dataset initialize start-----')
ox17_dataset, ox17_labels = oxflower17.load_data(one_hot=True)
train_dataset = ox17_dataset[:1024, :, :, :]
train_labels = ox17_labels[:1024, :]

test_dataset = ox17_dataset[1024:, :, :, :]
test_lables = ox17_labels[1024:, :]
print('Training dataset size is {}'.format(train_dataset.shape))
print('Test dataset size is {}'.format(test_dataset.shape))
print('-----Dataset initialize complete-----')


# initialize all weights and variables
def get_alexnet_variables(output_class_num):
    with tf.name_scope('conv1'):
        w1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=[11, 11, 3, 96], stddev=0.1), name='w1')
        b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([96]), name='b1')
    with tf.name_scope('conv2'):
        w2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=[5, 5, 96, 256], stddev=0.1), name='w2')
        b2 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(1.0, shape=[256]), name='b2')
    with tf.name_scope('conv3'):
        w3 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=[3, 3, 256, 384], stddev=0.1), name='w3')
        b3 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([384]), name='b3')
    with tf.name_scope('conv4'):
        w4 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=[3, 3, 384, 384], stddev=0.1), name='w4')
        b4 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(1.0, shape=[384]), name='b4')
    with tf.name_scope('conv5'):
        w5 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=[3, 3, 384, 256], stddev=0.1), name='w5')
        b5 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([256]), name='b5')
    with tf.name_scope('fc6'):
        w6 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=[(224 // 2 ** 5) * (224 // 2 ** 5) * 256, 4096], stddev=0.1),
                        name='w6')
        b6 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(1.0, shape=[4096]), name='b6')
    with tf.name_scope('fc7'):
        w7 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=[4096, 4096], stddev=0.1), name='w7')
        b7 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(1.0, shape=[4096]), name='b7')
    with tf.name_scope('fc8'):
        w8 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=[4096, output_class_num], stddev=0.1), name='w8')
        b8 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(1.0, shape=[output_class_num]), name='b8')

    variables = dict(w1=w1, w2=w2, w3=w3, w4=w4, w5=w5, w6=w6, w7=w7, w8=w8, b1=b1, b2=b2, b3=b3, b4=b4, b5=b5, b6=b6,
                    b7=b7, b8=b8)

    return variables


# build alexnet
def alexnet(variables, input_data, keep_prob_for_net):
    # layer one : conventional layer
    with tf.name_scope('conv1'):
        conv1 = tf.nn.conv2d(input_data, variables['w1'], strides=[1, 4, 4, 1], padding='SAME')
        conv1 = tf.nn.bias_add(conv1, variables['b1'])
        conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv1)
        conv1 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv1, ksize=[1, 3, 3, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')
        conv1 = tf.nn.local_response_normalization(conv1)

    # layer two : conventional layer
    with tf.name_scope('conv2'):
        conv2 = tf.nn.conv2d(conv1, variables['w2'], strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
        conv2 = tf.nn.bias_add(conv2, variables['b2'])
        conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2)
        conv2 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv2, ksize=[1, 3, 3, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')
        conv2 = tf.nn.local_response_normalization(conv2)

    # layer three: conventional layer
    with tf.name_scope('conv3'):
        conv3 = tf.nn.conv2d(conv2, variables['w3'], strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
        conv3 = tf.nn.bias_add(conv3, variables['b3'])
        conv3 = tf.nn.relu(conv3)

    # layer four: conventional layer
    with tf.name_scope('conv4'):
        conv4 = tf.nn.conv2d(conv3, variables['w4'], strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
        conv4 = tf.nn.bias_add(conv4, variables['b4'])
        conv4 = tf.nn.relu(conv4)

    # layer five: conventional layer
    with tf.name_scope('conv5'):
        conv5 = tf.nn.conv2d(conv4, variables['w5'], strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
        conv5 = tf.nn.bias_add(conv5, variables['b5'])
        conv5 = tf.nn.relu(conv5)
        conv5 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv5, ksize=[1, 3, 3, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')
        conv5 = tf.nn.local_response_normalization(conv5)

    # flat data
    with tf.name_scope('flatten'):
        flatten = tf.reshape(conv5, shape=[-1, (224 // 2 ** 5) * (224 // 2 ** 5) * 256])

    # layer six: fully connected layer
    with tf.name_scope('fc6'):
        fc6 = tf.matmul(flatten, variables['w6']) + variables['b6']
        fc6 = tf.nn.tanh(fc6)
        fc6 = tf.nn.dropout(fc6, keep_prob=keep_prob_for_net)

    # layer seven: fully connected layer
    with tf.name_scope('fc7'):
        fc7 = tf.matmul(fc6, variables['w7']) + variables['b7']
        fc7 = tf.nn.tanh(fc7)
        fc7 = tf.nn.dropout(fc7, keep_prob=keep_prob_for_net)

    # layer eight: fully connected layer
    with tf.name_scope('fc8'):
        logits_output = tf.matmul(fc7, variables['w8']) + variables['b8']

    return logits_output


# define placeholder, loss and accuracy
network_input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 224, 224, 3])
true_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 17])
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

# network output
y_ = alexnet(get_alexnet_variables(17), network_input, keep_prob)

# cross entropy loss
cross_entropy_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(labels=true_labels, logits=y_))
tf.summary.scalar('cross entropy', cross_entropy_loss)

# training step
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cross_entropy_loss)

# calculate accuracy
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_, 1), tf.argmax(true_labels, 1))

accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
tf.summary.scalar('accuracy', accuracy)

# run training process
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print('-----Training Start-----')
    merged = tf.summary.merge_all()
    train_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(log_dir + '/train', sess.graph)
    test_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(log_dir + '/test')
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
    i = 0
    for j in range(1000):
        i += 1
        if i * batch_size > 1024:
            i = 1
        print('Train step {} running {}/1024 to {}/1024'.format(j, (i - 1) * batch_size, i * batch_size))
        batch_image = train_dataset[(i - 1) * batch_size:i * batch_size, :, :, :]
        batch_label = train_labels[(i - 1) * batch_size:i * batch_size, :]
        run_options = tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE)
        run_metadata = tf.RunMetadata()
        # train_step.run(feed_dict={network_input: batch_image, true_labels: batch_label, keep_prob: 0.5})
        summary, _ = sess.run([merged, train_step],
        feed_dict={network_input: batch_image, true_labels: batch_label, keep_prob: 0.5},
        run_metadata=run_metadata, options=run_options)
        train_writer.add_summary(summary, j)
        if j % 10 == 0:
            print('Train Step {}, Current Test Accuracy is {}'.format(j, accuracy.eval(feed_dict={network_input:batch_image,
                                                                                        true_labels: batch_label,
                                                                                        keep_prob: 1.0})))

    print('-----Training Complete-----')
    print('-----Test Start-----')
    print('Test Accuracy is {}'.format(
        accuracy.eval(feed_dict={network_input: test_dataset, true_labels: test_lables, keep_prob: 1.0})))
    print('-----Test Complete-----')
```

During training, tensorboard show **accuracy** and **cross entropy** defind in above code. Here are the results:

Results for **accuracy**:
[image]

Results for **cross entropy**[image]

As you can see, the accuracy is bouncing up and down around value 1/17 which is equal to random selection accuracy. At the same time, cross entropy loss is above 10.

When I use code from [tflearn/alexnet](https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/blob/master/examples/images/alexnet.py) to compare results, the loss is decreased from 1.7 to 0.9 and accuracy increased from 0.1 to 0.9. So, I must did something wrong here.

After 1000 iteration, the test accuracy is 0.476 which is worse than random selection.

I have checked model definition, variables declaration and loss but could not find out the reason I get unexpected results.

I have also tried to change learning rate to 0.1 or change batch size to 10/64/128 and nothing changed.

Thanks in advance for anyone could help.

Comment: Have you tried a smaller learning rate, e.g. 1E-4, 1E-5?

Comment: I mean the network seems to be learning something, but only marginally. This is an indicator that the learning rate is too high and that it overshoots all the time. However, it could also be some unrelated obscure bug in the code.

Comment: I tried to change learning rate to 1E-5 and results seems to be better, test accuracy after 1000 training iteration is 0.44, much better than before. I'll do more test tonight. If learning rate too high is indeed the problem, I'll answer my own question. Very good suggestion, thanks a lot @ThomasPinetz.

Comment: By the way,  do you have more suggestions for deep-learning beginners regarding setting right learing rate?. Cuz I just rely on others' learning rate settings and it seems to be not a good approach.

Comment: Just try out different learning rates. Start with the baseline, given in different papers and adapt from there in both directions. With time you will get a feeling for what is wrong with your model.

Answer (score 0):

As @ThomasPinetz point out, learning rate too **high** caused this problem.

After changing learning rate from 0.001 to 1E-5, and extending training iteration from 1000 to 15000, I get following results from tensorboard:

Accuracy:
[accuracy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBwOz.jpg)

Cross Entropy Loss:
[cross entropy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xaf4X.jpg)

After training, the test accuracy is **0.7410**, which is fairly acceptable without fine-tuning.

Comment: I can't post images since it requires 10 reputation points at least, just click the link and see result pictures.